# Keras : TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'nb_depth')

Tags: python, keras-2

I am using Keras library for videos in python.
My Keras version is 2.0.2

```
 kernel_size=3
 model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution3D(nb_filters[0], kernel_size,nb_depth=nb_conv[0], nb_row=nb_conv[0], 
    nb_col=nb_conv[0],input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols, patch_size), 
    activation='relu'))
```

I am getting the following error.

```
 Using Theano Backened
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Project/codes/foreg.py", line 131, in <module>
    input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols, patch_size), activation='relu'))
  File "C:\Users\lenov\Anaconda3\envs\3dcnn\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenov\Anaconda3\envs\3dcnn\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 580, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenov\Anaconda3\envs\3dcnn\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 100, in __init__
    super(_Conv, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenov\Anaconda3\envs\3dcnn\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 277, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'nb_depth')
```

Kindly help me with this error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the kernel size right after the number of filters, such as:

```
kernel_size = 3
model.add(Convolution3D(nb_filters[0], kernel_size, nb_depth=nb_conv[0], nb_row=nb_conv[0], 
    nb_col=nb_conv[0],input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols, patch_size), 
    activation='relu'))
```

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv3d):

> kernel_size: An integer or tuple/list of 3 integers, specifying the width and height of the 3D convolution window. Can be a single integer to specify the same value for all spatial dimensions.

Comment: I gave the kernel size then I am getting the above error. I made the changes

Comment: There is no such argument as "nb_depth", or any of the other keywords you pass, for that matter! You can only pass arguments that correspond to the following keywords:
strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate, activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says: you did not provide kernel_size argument for Convolution3D constructor.

Check out [documentation](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/2.0.2/layers/convolutional/).

From documentation:

> **Conv3D**(filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='valid',
>   data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1, 1), activation=None,
>   use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
>   bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None,
>   bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None,
>   kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)

Comment: I added the kernel_size but then I am getting the above error

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by installing mkdocs

```
pip install mkdocs
```

in the working environment.